# System table with function's definitions in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I would like to make correction in triggers, but there are like 200-300 cases of this issue - far too much to do it manually. Is there any table with whole db code in Postgresql where I could just find all their definitions and correct them all at the same time?

That's probably beginner question (I know there's table like that in Oracle, but I'm new to Postgresql) but I can't seem to find it neither in web nor on my own.

Comment: Easiest is to use `pg_dump -U the_user --schema-only the_dbname >>textfile.sql`, and use the contents of the textfile. The textfile will contain **all** the DDL, including tables, indexes, views, functions, but these are easy to delete from the textfile.

Comment: Seems helpful. What directory does the file appear in? Can't seem to find it with 'find -name 'textfile*' but I'm not really effective when working on linux

Comment: There is no file. output is sent to stdout. (in my example, I redirected it to a file with `>>textfile` ) There is also an `--file=FILENAME` option/flag to the pg_dump command

Comment: I've used -f (as I understand it works the same way as --file) but nothing really happens. I mean whole thing doesn't even last 1-2 sec which seems impossible to me. As a filename do I put only the name, or maybe whole directory? and will it create the file,, or do I have to create empty file with that name beforehand? And last thing - do I put all this in psql? Or maybe somehow in postgresql editor?

Comment: pg_dump is a command (program); you run it by typing its name (plus the arguments) on the (linux) command line. And yes: it is fast, 1..2 sec is certainly possible. [linux] if a filename does not contain a directory path, the current directory is assumed.

Comment: Thanks for help. Somehow made the change I wanted even with my lacking Postgresql knowledge. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table that contains the definitions for all procedures in postgres is `pg_catalog.pg_proc`.

The column with the source code is `prosrc`.

You can do something like:

`select proname, prosrc from pg_proc where proname like '%doc%';`

assuming you have some functions named *doc*.

The stored procedure  `pg_catalog.pg_get_functiondef` will return the source code of a particular function.  You can do something like:

`select pg_get_functiondef(oid) from pg_proc where proname='myfunction_name';`

Unfortunately, `pg_get_functiondef` uses an aggregate function internally -- so you cannot call `pg_get_functiondef` in a query that is returning more than one function.

Comment: Already used the work-around with pg_dump, but pg_proc table is exactly what I was looking for, and it certainly will be useful in another case like that. Thanks for help.